# How to send unicode characters to servlet by ajax??

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, forms, multipartform-data

I am working on a login page which has a form of enctype multipart/formdata that contains input fields where user inputs data of any language. I am using **ajax** (**FormData**) to send the data to the server ,at the server i am not getting the data properly as i am not able to convert to unicode.  I have set page encoding to utf-8. I guess there's problem with the headers. **Somebody please help me.**

Here's my code :

**Client:**

```
                    var formdata=new FormData();
                    formdata.append("servname",servname);
                    formdata.append("disptype1",disptype1);
                    formdata.append("text",text);
                    formdata.append("back",back);
                    formdata.append("servtype",servtype);
                    formdata.append("caption",caption);
                    formdata.append("selsubservices",selsubservices);
                    formdata.append("action","addinfo");
                    formdata.append("iconfile",iconfile);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: 'settingServlet',
                        data: formdata,
                        //dataType: 'json',
                        //contentType: "multipart/form-data",
                        //processData: false,
                        contentType:false,
                        processData:false,
                        success: function (response) {     
                            processAddResponse(response);
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            alert("Error occured at" +error);
                        }
                    });
```

**Server :**

```
boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
            if (isMultipart)
              {
                DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
                ServletFileUpload uploads = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
                List<FileItem> formItems = uploads.parseRequest(request);
                if (formItems != null && formItems.size() > 0)
                  {
                    for (FileItem item : formItems)
                      {
                        if (item.isFormField())
                          {
                            //upload formdata except files
                            String fieldname = item.getFieldName();

                            if (fieldname.equals("roomname"))
                          {
                           name = item.getString();//data corrupts here.
                           name = new String(roomname.getBytes("iso-8859-1"),"UTF-8");
                           name = convert(roomname);
                           name = JUtility.toHTML(roomname);
                          }
                       }
                   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the contentType element in the ajax options as documented here:

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

I don't think you are using it properly right now (not sure what `contentType:false`, does actually)

Comment: I had to set ContentType:false because i couldn't handle the multipart data correctly.